# How to check if exist multiple object properties inside an array and get a value if it's true using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, c, object

I need to compare values inside a object in a Array and get a value if it's true.
Example:

```
let x = 1;
let y = 2;
let fruit;
Myarray = [
{numX = 1, numY = 2, Fruit: "Apple"},
{numX = 3, numY = 4, Fruit: "Orange"}
]

console.log(fruit)
```

I need to put the Fruit property inside the variable "fruit" if is true;

Comment: Please provide expected output (I did not get at all what you want to achieve)

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, did not help much :-D put some `console.log` to your code with a comment exactly what value you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to filter `Myarray` to only element which match the given x/y pair?  Something like this:

```
let results = Myarray.filter(item => item.numX === x && item.numY === y);
```

For the given test data, `results` would end up being an array wity a single element:

```
[
  {numX = 1, numY = 2, Fruit: "Apple"}
]
```

From there you can grab the value, assuming you just want the one:

```
results.length > 0 && console.log(results[0].Fruit);
```

---

If you're sure there could only be one matching element or want to ignore more than the first match, you could also use `.find()`:

```
let result = Myarray.find(item => item.numX === x && item.numY === y);
result && console.log(result.Fruit);
```

Comment: I need to put the fruit property inside a variable, I updated the qusestion.

Comment: @JSSantana: Is there anything that stops you from doing that?  For example: `let fruit = result.Fruit;`